# no matching function c++

Tags: c++, qt

i'm learning C++ and I run into a problem. I'm trying to make a simple web browser. It maybe because i use Class MainWindow in WebWiew. If i included MainWindow in WebWiew, the compiler says that the class MainWindow does not exist.

The problem occurs when I connect WebView with the interface.
I make a short version of my program.

`webview.cpp:6: erreur : no matching function for call to 'WebView::connect(WebView* const, const char*, MainWindow*&, const char*)';`

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets>
#include "webview.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:    
    MainWindow();

public slots:
    void adressChanged(QUrl url);
    void setTabTitle(QString title);
    void setProgressionValue(int value);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

```
#ifndef WEBVIEW_H
#define WEBVIEW_H

#include <QWebView>

class MainWindow;

class WebView : public QWebView
{
public:
    WebView(MainWindow *interface, QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    MainWindow *interface;

};

#endif // WEBVIEW_H
```

---

```
#include "webview.h"

WebView::WebView(MainWindow *interface, QWidget *parent) : QWebView(parent), interface(interface)
{
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(titleChanged(QString)), this->interface, SLOT(setTabTitle(QString)));
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(urlChanged(QUrl)), this->interface, SLOT(adressChanged(QUrl)));
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(loadProgress(int)), this->interface, SLOT(setProgressionValue(int)));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `#include "mainwindow.h"` in your webview.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `QObject::connect()` method class `MainWindow` must be fully qualified. In your case you just forward declare it, so compiler has no idea, that `MainWindow` is inherited from  `QMainWindow`. Just add `#include "mainwindow.h"` into webview.cpp